# Jpos transaction testing using jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins, jpos

I want to test jpos transaction using netcat command in jmeter any ideas about it ? I want to hit isomsg usinh netcat command

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about [this netcat](https://linux.die.net/man/1/nc) command you can run it via JMeter's [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler)

[image: JMeter OS Process Sampler Netcat]

You can run any program or command using the OS Process Sampler, pass any parameters to it, check execution time, validate output using [Assertions](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#assertions), etc.

See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) guide for more details.

Comment: Can i test jpos transaction using Tcp sampler sending isomsg xml format in text to send field

Comment: Sure, you can, see [How to Load Test TCP Protocol Services with JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-tcp-protocol-services-jmeter) article to get familiarized with the concept.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i have made the plugin jmeter for jpos. And i am have been using this for testing :)

https://github.com/erlanggaelfallujah/JMeter-jPOS-components

Comment: I'm getting error while building this project can you give me the jar i'm using jmeter 3.2